Question about the proof of General Sobolev Inequality
I am reading the Partial Differential Equaiton by Evans. In the book the general Sobolev inequality states that (its first part):
Let $U$ be open and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $C^1$ boundary. Then for $u \in W^{k, p} (U)$ and $k<\frac{n}{p}$, where $1 \leq p < \infty$, we have $$ \Vert u \Vert_{L^q(U)} \leq C \Vert u \Vert_{W^{k,p}(U)} ,$$ for $\frac{1}{q} = \frac{1}{p} - \frac{k}{n}$.
In the proof, the book argues that, for all $\beta$ that $|\beta| \leq k-1$, by Gagliador-Nirenberg-Sobolev (I will write this as GNS for short) inequality we have
$$
\Vert D^{\beta} u \Vert_{L^{p^*}} \leq C \Vert u \Vert_{W^{k,p}} \quad\quad  (|\beta| \leq k-1).
$$
Here we can apply the GNS inequality because by assumption $k p < n$ for $k \geq 1$ and thus $p < n$. Then we have
$$
u \in W^{k-1, p^*} (U)
$$
by the preceeding inequality.
Then the author says that we apply the same procedure to $u \in W^{k-1, p^*} (U)$, then we get $u \in W^{k-2, p^{**}} (U)$, and we note that $\frac{1}{p^{**}} = \frac{1}{p} - \frac{2}{n}$. Doing this repeatively for $k$ times, we arrive at $u \in W^{0, q}$, which is just $L^q$, where $\frac{1}{q} = \frac{1}{p} - \frac{k}{n}$.
My question is, indeed we can use GNS inequality in the first step, but from the second step, since for $u \in W^{k-1, p^*} (U)$, $p^*$ might not satisfy $p^* < n$, why can we continue using the GNS inequality?
For example, let $n = 3$ and $p = 2$, then $p^* = 1/(\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{n}) = 6 > n$, and the condition for GNS inequality ($p^* < n$) is not meet.

If you carefully check the text,you will find the condition for this argument is $kp<n$ rather than $p<n$.
For your example, $k\ge2$ must hold, then $4=2p<n=3$ does not hold.

Thank you. I forgot to consider the value of $k$ .
